# Xcode UI on background thread to render image

Tags: xcode, multithreading, uikit

I'm rendering an image with text for one of my apps and has a noticeable impact on UI performance (can be as big as ~1 second freeze), so I am doing it on a background thread. Since the image has text, using `UILabel`s and other `UIView`s makes it easy to lay everything out, and I render the view containing everything to an image.

However, I get a warning from Xcode saying that it's not allowed on the background thread because it uses UIKit. Why am I not allowed to call UIKit on the background thread even though my use case is completely self-contained and isolated from any rendering onscreen?

To help the code below make more sense, it draws an image that is a listing of several items, each of which consists of two small square images and the name of the item all in a row. The list can have several columns. The code has been tweaked slightly (mostly variable names) to avoid showing proprietary code, but does the same job.

My code:

```
NSArray<MyItem*>* items;  // These are the items that I'm drawing. They
                          // get set before the following code is called.

// Processing code:
const CGFloat TITLE_FONT_SIZE = 50;     // font size of the title
const CGFloat ITEM_FONT_SIZE = 25;      // font size of the item names
const int OUTER_PADDING = 60;           // padding from the edge of the image to the main content
const int ROW_PADDING = 13;             // padding between rows
const int COL_PADDING = 100;            // padding between columns
const int PADDING = 20;                 // padding between content items in a row
const int BOX_SIZE = 25;                // how high/wide each image is
const int ROW_HEIGHT = BOX_SIZE;        // pixel height of a line
const int COL_WIDTH = 500;              // pixel width of a column (image1, image2, and name)

// compute the dimensions of the image
UILabel* titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:TITLE_FONT_SIZE];
titleLabel.text = @"My image";
[titleLabel sizeToFit];
titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(OUTER_PADDING, OUTER_PADDING / 2, titleLabel.frame.size.width, titleLabel.frame.size.height);

const int MIN_NUM_COLS = 1 + ((titleLabel.frame.size.width - COL_WIDTH) / (COL_WIDTH + COL_PADDING));
const int NORMAL_NUM_COLS = (int)ceil(sqrt([items count] / (COL_WIDTH / (ROW_HEIGHT))));
const int NUM_COLS = (MIN_NUM_COLS > NORMAL_NUM_COLS ? MIN_NUM_COLS : NORMAL_NUM_COLS);
const int NUM_ROWS = (int)ceil([items count] / (float)NUM_COLS);
const int NUM_OVERFLOW_ROWS = [items count] % NUM_ROWS;

const int titleWidth = titleLabel.frame.size.width;
const int defaultWidth = (NUM_COLS * (COL_WIDTH + COL_PADDING)) - COL_PADDING;
const int pixelWidth = (2 * OUTER_PADDING) + (titleWidth > defaultWidth ? titleWidth : defaultWidth);
const int pixelHeight = (2 * OUTER_PADDING) + (TITLE_FONT_SIZE + PADDING) + (NUM_ROWS * (ROW_HEIGHT + ROW_PADDING)) - ROW_PADDING;
const int nbytes = 4 * pixelHeight * pixelWidth;

byte* data = (byte*)malloc(sizeof(byte) * nbytes);
memset(data, 255, nbytes);

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, pixelWidth, pixelHeight, 8, 4 * pixelWidth, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);

// --------------------------------------------------
// create a view heirarchy and then draw to our context
UIView* mainView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[mainView addSubview:titleLabel];

// setup all the views
int keyIndex = 0;
CGFloat x = OUTER_PADDING;
CGFloat starty = titleLabel.frame.origin.y + titleLabel.frame.size.height + PADDING;

for (int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
{   
    int nrows = (col == NUM_COLS + 1 ? NUM_OVERFLOW_ROWS : NUM_ROWS);
    CGFloat y = starty;

    for (int row = 0; (row < nrows) && (keyIndex < [items count]); row++)
    {
        CGFloat tempx = x;
        MyItem* item = [items objectAtIndex:keyIndex];

        UIImageView* imageview1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:item.image1];
        imageview1.frame = CGRectMake(tempx, y, BOX_SIZE, BOX_SIZE);
        [mainView addSubview:imageview1];
        tempx += BOX_SIZE + PADDING;

        UIImageView* imageview2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:item.imageview2];
        imageview2.frame = CGRectMake(tempx, y, BOX_SIZE, BOX_SIZE);
        [mainView addSubview:imageview2];
        tempx += BOX_SIZE + PADDING;

        UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:ITEM_FONT_SIZE];
        label.text = item.name;
        [label sizeToFit];
        label.center = CGPointMake(tempx + (label.frame.size.width / 2), imageview2.center.y);
        [mainView addSubview:label];

        y += ROW_HEIGHT + ROW_PADDING;
        keyIndex++;
    }

    x += COL_WIDTH + COL_PADDING;
}

// --------------------------------------------------
// draw everything to actually generate the image
CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, pixelHeight));

[mainView.layer renderInContext:context];

CGImageRef cgimage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
myCoolImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimage];

CGImageRelease(cgimage);
CGContextRelease(context);
free(data);
```

Comment: You don’t need labels etc to construct an image so basically it’s you that are drawing incorrectly

Comment: @matt Agreed, I don't NEED them, but it does make it easier and more dynamic to lay things out. Plus that begs the question: if it's incorrect, why do the methods to do it exist? They aren't private APIs either, which would be expected if we weren't supposed to call them.

Comment: Being able to snapshot a view or a piece of the view hierarchy is important when you're doing animation. That is why the UIView snapshot methods exist. But in that case, the view is in the hierarchy and you need to be on the main thread. CALayer's `render(in:)` is not UIKit, but it is for detached layers, not a view's underlying layer. Again I say, there is a right way to draw text to an image and it sounds like you were never doing it in the first place — which could explain why your image rendering is so unconscionably slow. If you show some of your code, I could explain how to draw right.

Comment: @matt Posted code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've established in comments, what you're doing is both illegitimate and slow.

Arranging and sizing UILabel and UIImageView objects is slow, and calling
CALayer `renderInContext` is *really* slow.

And it isn't how you draw.

Everything you're doing has its analogue in the actual drawing world (Quartz 2D), and if you did it that way, not only would it be legal in the background, it probably wouldn't even *need* to be in the background because it would be so much faster. So:

- Every place you use a UILabel, you can achieve *exactly* the same effect by using NSAttributedString `draw...` commands.
- Every place you use a UIImageView, you can achieve *exactly* the same effect by using UIImage `draw...` commands.

Any of us who does any extensive drawing has learned to create structured layouts of the type you're making by using actual drawing code, and now is your chance to learn to do it too.